# Magento2 : How to get order-total in shipping email

Tags: magento2, shipping, email-templates

I like to get order-total in shipping email template of magento 2.3

[image]

Comment: $total=$order->getGrandTotal();

Comment: It completely hidden "Latest despatched items " table